# Expandable tableView in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

[image]

I want to make this type of **expandable/collapsible** table view.
there are categories and subcategories as in picture.
for example "health and beauty" is a category and when i click this cell than its open subcategories as in picture below.
So how can I make this type of table view?
please suggest me.

Comment: For swift3, You can check this tutorial explaining custom Expandable and collapsable UITableView http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2017/03/expandable-and-collapsable-uitableview-using-Swift3.html

Comment: You can try this library for Swift 3 -> [ExpyTableView](https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView). It allows you to easily generate an expandable table view just by implementing one method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i get two very useful helping link below which describes exact what the requirement is here
[Expanding/Collapsing TableView Sections](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)
[Collapsable Table View for iOS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Collapsable-Table-View-for-iOS)

Really, good articles for such kind of expanding/collapsing tableview sections

Comment: One more link written using swift3 http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2017/03/expandable-and-collapsable-uitableview-using-Swift3.html

Answer (score 10):

Use Following code for expandable Cell into UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];    
    return cell;
}
```

code for expanding & collapsing rows – TableView DidSelectRow Method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break; 
        }
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {        
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
    }
}
```

A Method which will help to minimize & maximize/expand-collapse rows.

```
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];        
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }
        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

You can download the [source code from my tutorial site](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/).

Answer (score 8):

If this helps: [Access uitableview's expandable and collapsable sections] https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView

Comment: There is now a Swift version of this expandable table view library here ->  [ExpyTableView](https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView) . It does not have downloadDataForSection and UIExpansionState notifier but all the other functionality are written in Swift and exists in new library.

Answer (score 6):

I have a little bit of a different approach to expandable table views - one that aligns with how these kinds of table views are generally built.

There are **headers** and there are **cells**. **Headers** should be *tappable*, and then **cells** underneath the headers would *show or hide*. This can be achieved by adding a gesture recognizer to the header, and when tapped, you just remove all of the cells underneath that header (the section), and viceversa (add cells). Of course, you have to maintain state of which headers are "open" and which headers are "closed."

This is nice for a couple of reasons:

1. The job of headers and cells are separated which makes code cleaner.
2. This method flows nicely with how table views are built (headers and cells) and, therefore, there isn't much magic - the code is simply removing or adding cells, and should be compatible with later versions of iOS.

I made a very simple library to achieve this. As long as your table view is set up with UITableView section headers and cells, all you have to do is subclass the tableview and the header. Try it :)

Link: https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try Using this code... May be this can help..
And Feel free to Edit the code according to your requirements...

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTable;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //myTable.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   // self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
    muArr= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Vinay",@"Anmol",@"Jagriti", nil];
    ExpArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Useeee",@"Thissss",@"Codeee", nil];
    otherExpand=100;
    checker=100;

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return muArr.count;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(otherExpand==section)
    return ExpArr.count;

    return  0;

}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)table canCollapse:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return NO;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Identifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[ExpArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *viewww=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    viewww.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
    cell.backgroundView=viewww;

   // cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    return cell;

}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [view1.layer setCornerRadius:20];
    view1.layer.borderWidth=2;
    view1.layer.borderColor=[UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 295, 44)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    label.text=[muArr objectAtIndex:section];
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(280, -5, 50, 50);
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    btn.tag=section;

    view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
    label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"American TypeWriter" size:18];
    //btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [view1 addSubview:btn];
    [view1 addSubview:label];

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Btntap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return view1;
}


-(void)Btntap : (UIButton *)btn
{
    if(otherExpand!=100)
    {
        if (otherExpand==btn.tag)
        {
            NSMutableArray *tempArr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(int j=0;j<ExpArr.count;j++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *indexx1=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:otherExpand];
                [tempArr2 addObject:indexx1];
            }
            checker=0;
            otherExpand=100;
            [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArr2 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }

        else
        {
            NSMutableArray *tempArr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(int j=0;j<ExpArr.count;j++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *indexx1=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:otherExpand];
                [tempArr2 addObject:indexx1];
            }
            checker=1;
            otherExpand=100;
            [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArr2 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }

    if(checker!=0)
    {
        otherExpand=btn.tag;
        //checker=
        NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<ExpArr.count;i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexx=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:btn.tag];
            [tempArr addObject:indexx];
        }
        [myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        checker=1;
    }
    checker=100;
}



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44;
}

@end
```

Comment: I tried it but not getting same thing as i want because my dictionary is dynamic

Comment: @VinayKumar I have copy paste the code but it is not expanding could you  help me with the code?

Comment: @Vinay Kumar.. If i want to add different rows in each section means how can i modify . Suppose if section1=4,section2=6.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi This is one of the codes that I used very long time ago. The better way to create Expand-Collapse Cells with sections is to Place a button in the Section Header. And when that button is pressed you have to insert the rows(with animation) in that particular section.

Comment: @VinayKumar.. After long time i have to work with expand tableview. I want to expand section or row. How can i achieve this could u please guide me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 4):

There is a great video in WWDC 2011 called [UITableView Changes, Tips and Tricks - session 125](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) that shows how to do things like this.
Also check out the example code [TVAnimationsGestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at this accordion example in Swift: https://github.com/tadija/AEAccordion

[image]

It's got very little code to create accordion effect (not by using sections but cells), and as a bonus there is also a solution to use XIB files inside other XIB files (useful for custom cells which use custom views).

Answer (score 2):

Please try this example :

best example for Expandable TableView

https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView

Answer (score 1):

[TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) can do this sort of thing naturally. In fact, there is are extensions for both expandable sections and expandable tree structures. Try running the [Collapse](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Collapse/Collapse/CollapseTableViewController.m) sample project for expandable sections and the [Outline sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m) for expandable trees.

One advantage of using TLIndexPathTools is that, as a simple, low-level API, it can solve all kinds of dynamic table view and collection view problems using a common approach. And it works interchangeably with Core Data and plain arrays.

Answer (score 1):

it is so easy to create an expandable tableview
here is an example how I did this,

data I m using for this one

```
struct ItemList {
var name: String
var items: [String]
var collapsed: Bool

init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false) {
   self.name = name
   self.items = items
   self.collapsed = collapsed
   }
}

var sections = [ItemList]()

var items: [ItemList] = [
 ItemList(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air"]),
 ItemList(name: "iPad", items: ["iPad Pro", "iPad Air 2"]),
 ItemList(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 7", "iPhone 6"])
]
```

now just add this piece of code and use accordingly

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerHeading = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 30, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20))
    if items[section].collapsed{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "collapsed")
    }else{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "expand")
    }
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60))
    let tapGuesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerViewTapped))
    tapGuesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGuesture)
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    headerView.tag = section
    headerHeading.text = items[section].name
    headerHeading.textColor = .white
    headerView.addSubview(headerHeading)
    headerView.addSubview(imageView)
    return headerView
 }
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let itms = items[section]
    return !itms.collapsed ? 0 : itms.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
@objc func headerViewTapped(tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print(tapped.view?.tag)
    if items[tapped.view!.tag].collapsed == true{
        items[tapped.view!.tag].collapsed = false
    }else{
        items[tapped.view!.tag].collapsed = true
    }
    if let imView = tapped.view?.subviews[1] as? UIImageView{
        if imView.isKind(of: UIImageView.self){
            if items[tapped.view!.tag].collapsed{
                imView.image = UIImage(named: "collapsed")
            }else{
                imView.image = UIImage(named: "expand")
            }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

}
```

and the result is Bingo :)

[image]

Comment: how to use DidSelectRow at Index method ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the requirement of expanding a single cell to a fuller view and collapsing it back to a summarised view.

So what I did was to design my cell using `UIStackView`. And I kept the view I didn't want to show in the collapsed state hidden and then showing it when the cell was tapped.

The trick here is to show and hide the view within `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` statements. In this way table view automatically adjusts the cell height and does it animatedly.

Here is how a basic cell would look in the IB:
[image]

Cells Custom Class:

```
    class AccordionCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var extendedDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    var expanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if let extended = self.extendedDescriptionLabel {
                extended.isHidden = !expanded
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.expanded = false
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }    
}
```

UITableView Delegate Implementation:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! AccordionCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.expanded = indexPath.row == expanded
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AccordionCell {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            if expanded == indexPath.row {
                cell.expanded = false
                expanded = -1
            }
            else {
                cell.expanded = true
                expanded = indexPath.row
            }
            
            tableView.endUpdates()
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AccordionCell {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            cell.expanded = false
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

In order to keep track which cell is expanded, I introduced a variable saving `indexpath` of currently expanded cell so that the right cell is expanded when tableview is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Link :

http://iostechnotips.blogspot.in/2014/05/expandable-uitableview.html

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

*Use `UITableView` delegate method `viewForHeaderInSection` and return a custom UIView.

*Add a `UIButton` as subview with action "expandable:(id)sender" check the sender id as section number and reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file

```
LoadCustomCell *cell1;
NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;
NSMutableArray  *questionArray;
NSMutableArray  *answerArray;
```

In your .m file

```
 viewDidLoadMethod {
 _faqTblView.estimatedRowHeight = 30;
 _faqTblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 arrayForBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 _questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 _answerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (int i = 0; i < _questionArray.count; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:@"0"];
    }
    self.faqTblView.dataSource = self;
    self.faqTblView .delegate = self;
    [self.faqTblView reloadData];
 }
```

after that

```
 #pragma mark - TableView Datasource & Delegate Method.
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return [_questionArray count];
 }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 100)];
    lblText.text = [_questionArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [lblText getLabelHeight] + 20;(created custom class)
 }
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
cell1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[cell1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell1.frame.size.width, cell1.frame.size.height)];
NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld. ",section + 1];
[cell1.sideMenuUserNameLabel setText:[numStr stringByAppendingString:[_questionArray objectAtIndex:section]]];
[cell1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
cell1.tag = section;
[cell1 addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

return cell1;
}

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < [_questionArray count]; i++) {
        if (indexPath.section==i) {
            [arrayForBool removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [arrayForBool insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", !collapsed] atIndex:i];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", arrayForBool);
    [self.faqTblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.faqTblView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
        [self.faqTblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
         }
    cell1.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
     }
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *questionCellIdentifier = @"questionCellIdentifier";
QuestionCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:questionCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray * myNib;
    myNib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"QuestionCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (QuestionCustomCell *)[myNib lastObject];
}

BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
if(manyCells){
    cell.questionNameLbl.text = [_answerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpyTableView](https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView)

Which makes an expandable section from your given cell. Compatible down to iOS 8.0. You will have flexibility by generating an expandable table view with multiple table view cells. Just manipulate the separators for states and then no one will know you are using multiple cells for expanding.

- **Other solutions:** You manipulate the height to expand a cell, when an update needed in design of the cell, you have to re-construct all the auto-layout constraints or logic in code.
- **ExpyTableView:** You make an expandable table view by using multiple cells and inserting and deleting them(which can mean expanding and collapsing), you will have a great chance in future design requests. All you will have to do is adding a new UITableViewCell and writing the code for it. You will easily have the new design.

All you have to do is to `import ExpyTableView` and then:

```
class ViewController: ExpyTableViewDataSource, ExpyTableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var expandableTableView: ExpyTableView!

  // First, set data source and delegate for your table view.
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    expandableTableView.dataSource = self
    expandableTableView.delegate = self
  }

  // Then return your expandable cell instance from expandingCell data source method.
  func expandableCell(forSection section: Int, inTableView tableView: ExpyTableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    // this cell will be displayed at IndexPath with section: section and row 0
  }
}
```

You can see your former table view section is now an expandable table view section. You can also download the [example project](https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView) and see more detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

**UITableView with Collapsible (expand and collapse) Cells swift 5**

- Very Easy to Use  with Custom Cells
- Expendable
- Dynamic Content

**Check Github Link :** https://github.com/Murteza12/ExpandableTablew/wiki/UITableView-with-Collapsible-(expand-and-collapse)-Cells

[image]