# Is it possible to have a collapsable table view in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I'd like to make a collapsable table view, something like the image shown in this question here: [Expandable tableView in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone)

At the moment I've got a device list that when you click on a button on the device list, it takes you to a new activity on a new page where information about that selection is listed. I'd instead like when making a selection, that table entry to expand and offer additional information like shown in the aforementioned image. If it's not possible, I'll probably just use a View Switcher.

Any indication about how to do that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html) for this. An example cam be found [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-expandablelistview-with-custom-adapter-baseexpandablelistadapter.html).