# How to expand the cell and insert row in it?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

As shown in the picture, Personal info, Education, Hobbies etc are the section header titles. Now I want to design my tableview as, the section headers will be cells and when I tap on it it will expand and the datas that are in the section will show on the expanded cell. Can anyone give me any idea how can I do that?

Since I am new I am not getting the idea how to do that.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone

Comment: https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView