# How to create UIButton on UITableview and display the list for each button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

How can I create list of buttons with expandable and collapse
in table view in objective C which should be displaying list of data from the web services.

Comment: Use this [expandable-tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone)

Comment: i will go through the links @the_dahiya_boy