# Swift: Expandable Static TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, expand

Before I post this, I have read some article like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone) or [this](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView) , but all of that example always using dynamic data. I want to know how implement expandable tableview in static data. I think this is more simple but I don't have any idea. My snippet code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if indexPath.row == self.department {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            datePickerFrom.isHidden = true
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            datePickerUntil.isHidden = true
        }
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let lastDepartment = self.department
        self.department = indexPath.row

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath, IndexPath.init(row: lastDepartment, section: 1)], with: .none)
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            datePickerFrom.isHidden = false
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            datePickerUntil.isHidden = false
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    if section == 0 {


    } else if section == 1 {
        count = 2
    } else if section == 2 || section == 3 {
        count = 1
    }

    return count
}
```

Let's say I have 4 section. I want make first section be expandable but with static table, cell and static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I read some example that using `Bool` value and set the height to manage expand and collapse cell. Here is my final code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let lastDepartment = self.department
        self.department = indexPath.row

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath, IndexPath.init(row: lastDepartment, section: 1)], with: .none)
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {

        if !isExpandToDate {
            if isExpandFromDate {
                isExpandFromDate = !isExpandFromDate
                isExpandToDate = !isExpandToDate
            } else {
                isExpandFromDate = !isExpandFromDate
            }
        } else {
            if isExpandFromDate {
                isExpandFromDate = !isExpandToDate
            } else {
                isExpandFromDate = !isExpandFromDate
            }
        }
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3 {

        if !isExpandFromDate {
            if isExpandToDate {
                isExpandToDate = !isExpandToDate
                isExpandFromDate = !isExpandFromDate
            } else {
                isExpandToDate = !isExpandToDate
            }
        } else {
            if isExpandToDate {
                isExpandToDate = !isExpandFromDate
            } else {
                isExpandToDate = !isExpandToDate
            }
        }
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isExpandFromDate && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        return 0
    }
    else if isExpandToDate && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4 {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW27):

> Static cells: Use static content to design the overall layout of the
> table, including the total number of cells. A table view with static
> content has a fixed set of cells that you can configure at design
> time. You can also configure other static data elements such as
> section headers. Use static cells when a table does not change its
> layout, regardless of the specific information it displays

In your scenario, since you are using a dynamic data source, you'll have to make your table view `dynamic`