# How to make sidemenu in swift (subSidemenu

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I made sidemenu. but i have some question. when i clicked button on the sidemenu, appear an other side button.
look like this image

[image]

when i clicked sidemenu button, appear subSidemenu. 
I don't know how to say this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expandable tableView in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone)

Comment: This functionality is called **Expandable-collapse tableview** & there are lots of answer available for this . Thats why I marked it duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to show a list of values which are collapsable then you need a `UITableView`. Make your `SideMenu`s as sections and rows as `SubSideMenu`s.
And you would like to have that feature when user tap so implement tableview's `numberOfRows` method like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sideMenu = mySideMenus[section]
    return sideMenu.isCollapsed ? 0 : sideMenu.subSideMenus.count
}
```

And when the header is tapped you need to call `tableView.reloadSections(sections: [IndexSet], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` to reload that section.

I don't know if this is was your exact question but sidebar is easy to implement for your app. And you don't need buttons when working with tableView.